# How to unflatten a flattened hierarchy with Streams API

Tags: java, java-8, tree, java-stream

If I have a hierarchical structure that is still sorted, but flattened - how can I create a parent/child structure with Java Streams API? An example:
How do I go from

```
-,A,Foo
A,A1,Alpha1
A,A2,Alpha2
-,B,Bar
B,B1,Bravo1
B,B2,Bravo2
```

to

```
-
  A
    A1,Alpha1
    A2,Alpha2
  B
    B1,Bravo1
    B2,Bravo2
```

A simple non-stream way would be to keep track of the parent column and see if it has changed.

I have tried various ways with Collectors and groupingBy, but have not yet found how to do.

```
List<Row> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Row("-", "A", "Root"));
list.add(new Row("A", "A1", "Alpha 1"));
list.add(new Row("A", "A2", "Alpha 2"));
list.add(new Row("-", "B", "Root"));
list.add(new Row("B", "B1", "Bravo 1"));
list.add(new Row("B", "B2", "Bravo 2"));

//Edit
Map<Row, List<Row>> tree;

tree = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(???))
```

Comment: I just edited the question above

Comment: In my current situation, there are no nested trees, but I'd love to see how that can be accomplished too.

Comment: (Moving from a deleted answer to here) I would suggest defining what exactly would your tree be like. Please edit the question and state, what is the relation between a parent node and a child node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a `Map` of each `Row` indexed by it's name:

```
Map<String,Row> nodes = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Row::getName,Function.identity()));
```

`getName()` being the second property passed to the `Row` constructor.

Now you can use that `Map` to build the tree:

```
Map<Row,List<Row>> tree = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r->nodes.get(r.getParent())));
```

`getParent()` being the first property passed to the `Row` constructor.

This would require the `Row` class to override `equals` and `hashCode` properly, so that two `Row` instances will be considered equal if they have the same name.

You should probably add a root `Row` to your input `List` though. Something like:

```
list.add(new Row(null, "-", "Root"));
```

EDIT:

I tested it with a full `Row` class (though I made some shortcuts), including an example of traversing the tree from the root along the first child of each level:

```
class Row {
    String name;
    String parent;
    Row (String parent,String name,String something) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getParent () {return parent;}
    public String getName () {return name;}

    public int hashCode () {return name.hashCode ();}
    public boolean equals (Object other) {
        return ((Row) other).name.equals (name);
    }
    public String toString ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        List<Row> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Row(null, "-", "Root"));
        list.add(new Row("-", "A", "Root"));
        list.add(new Row("A", "A1", "Alpha 1"));
        list.add(new Row("A1", "A11", "Alpha 11"));
        list.add(new Row("A", "A2", "Alpha 2"));
        list.add(new Row("-", "B", "Root"));
        list.add(new Row("B", "B1", "Bravo 1"));
        list.add(new Row("B", "B2", "Bravo 2"));
        Map<String,Row> nodes = 
            list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Row::getName,Function.identity()));
        Map<Row,List<Row>> tree = 
            list.stream()
                .filter(r->r.getParent()!= null)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r->nodes.get(r.getParent())));
        System.out.println (tree);
        Row root = nodes.get ("-");
        while (root != null) {
            System.out.print (root + " -> ");
            List<Row> children = tree.get (root);
            if (children != null && !children.isEmpty ()) {
                root = children.get (0);
            } else {
                root = null;
            }
        }
        System.out.println ();
    }
}
```

Output:

The tree:

```
{A1=[A11], A=[A1, A2], B=[B1, B2], -=[A, B]}
```

The traversal:

```
- -> A -> A1 -> A11 ->
```

Comment: If you do not want to create a `nodes` map, you can use `r -> list.stream().filter(li -> li.getName().equals(r.getParent())).findFirst().get()` as predicate for `groupingBy`.

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra that could be expensive if the input list is large.