# create map inside map by parsing string key

Tags: java

I have Map like this

```
{
tag=post,
body.patient.site = google.com,
body.patient.email = test@gmail.com,
body.patient.addresses.line1 = 44,
body.patient.addresses.line2 = 7th Street,
body.patient.addresses.city = Bangalore,
body.patient.addresses.state = KA
}
```

create nested Map by paring the key of input map

```
{
tag=post,
body={patient={site=google.com, email=test@gmail.com, 
       addresses={line1=44, line2=7th Steet, city=Bangalore, state=KA}}}
}
```

Comment: I don't see a Map here, just two blocks of text that vaguely resemble JSON. And what is that "string key" that is to be parsed according to your title? Please tell us what aspect of converting between these data structures is unclear to you.

Comment: Just a guess - are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54123464/how-to-unflatten-a-flattened-hierarchy-with-streams-api